# Maven and mysql dependency

Tags: mysql, maven, ant

I currently have a project in which there is a build.xml. In this build, there is the command CreateDB, which calls something.jar. This jar run some sql script (mysql db). So, right now, I can run that command by executing

```
ant CreateDB
```

from the command line. But now, I need to do something more. When I am building my application (using Maven), I want to run that ant command. So, I create this pom.xml (see below), but it doesn't work, I got this error :

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver'
```

According to this message, it seems that I don't have the connector for mySql, but I specified it in my dependency. So, what I did wrong ?

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.dl.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>toto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>toto</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.23</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>mysql</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <!-- For MySql -->
                <ant antfile="path\build.xml" target="createDB" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ant task launched by the maven antrun plugin does not inherit the maven dependencies automatically.

You have to reference the maven test classpath explicitly in your build.xml code, which is available through the `maven.test.classpath` property.

So your execution might look similar to the following (test.classpath also needs to referenced in your build.xml):

```
<execution>
   <id>mysql</id>
   <phase>integration-test</phase>
   <configuration>
      <tasks>
         <!-- For MySql -->
         <property name="test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath"/>
         <ant antfile="path\build.xml" target="createDB" />
      </tasks>
   </configuration>
   <goals>
       <goal>run</goal>
   </goals>
</execution>
```

See also: [Maven AntRun Plugin - Referencing the Maven Classpaths](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html)